when did Job live?
One way to find Job’s generation is to count the generations in the family tree for
Job's contemporary Elihu (though he was young, and likely in the next generation), and compare them to the Patriarch records. These are the scriptures:
Job 32:6: ”And Elihu the son of Barachel the Buzite answered and said, ‘I am young, and you are very old.” Gen 11:26: “And Terah lived seventy years, and begat Abram, Nahor, and Haran.” Gen. 22:20-23: “Behold, Milcah, she hath also born children unto
thy brother Nahor; Huz his firstborn, and Buz his brother…
So Nahor-Buz-Barachel-Elihu = Abram- Isaac-Jacob-Judah . That would place the
events of Job’s trials about the time of Jacob's sojourn in Canaan. It is curious that
Job’s lifespan does not match with Jacob’s at 147, but with Terah (205), Abram (175)
or Isaac's (180). However, Job seems to have had a blessing of a long life for his time. Others say Job lived later because of the use of term 'Rahab' (translated "proud") in 9:13 and 26:12; believing the use of this word is significant as it relates to later Egypt. Ps.87:4; Is.51:9.

This question has been asked before. You've also written what's really an answer, so you might like to copy it to that question instead.
